# Socket Fragmented Received Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create some kind of client monitor, like a terminal, to receive data from a serial device over ethernet. I'm trying to use a socket with python, but the problem comes when I create the connection. I'm supposed to receive only one message from the server, and I get the whole message but split into two packets, like this:

Message expected:

```
   b'-- VOID MESSAGE--'
```

Message received:

```
   b'-- VOID'
   b' MESSAGE--'
```

I don't know if is this a problem of buffer size, decoding or any other function

```
import socket        

TCP_IP = '192.168.#.#'
TCP_PORT = ### 
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
data1=' '

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

while(1):
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print(data.decode('ASCII'))


s.close()
```

I've already tried with some codecs options like UTF-8, UTF-16 and ASCII but I still get the same result.

---

This function helped me to solve the issue.

```
while(1):                                           
    cadena += s.recv(1)                            
    if (((cadena)[i])=='\n'):       
        print(cadena.decode('ASCII'))               
        cadena=b''                                  
        i=-1                                        

    i+=1
```

Comment: That's just how sockets work.  Even if a message is sent all in one piece, it isn't guaranteed to arrive all in one piece.  You have to keep reading until you get it all.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't have any code to receive or send messages, so it's not surprising that it doesn't.

Comment: Well, int he line data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) is where i'm receiving the data. I know 'cause i've al ready tried the code, and i get data, but not in the format that i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it already was said - that's how sockets works.
Sent data could be splitted to chunks. So if you want to be sure, that you've received whole message that was sent you need to implement some kind of protocol, the part of which will be contain length of your message. For example:

- First four bytes (integer) represents length of the message
- Other bytes - content of the message

In such case algorithm to send a message will be look like:

- Count length of the message
- Write to socket integer (4 bytes) with message length
- Write to socket content of the message

And reading algorithm:

- Read bytes from socket and write read data to accumulator-buffer
- Read first four bytes from buffer as integer - it will be message length
- Check if buffer length is greater or equal "{message length} + 4"
- If it's then read required amount of bytes and that will message that was sent.
- Drop first "{message length} + 4" bytes from buffer
- Repeat from second point
- If it's not enough bytes to read message content repeat from first point.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use UDP instead of TCP if you can live with the limitations:

1. There is a size limit, the data must fit into one packet
2. UDP is "unreliable".

A TCP connection transfer one single stream of bytes. OTOH UDP transfers individual datagrams (messages). If the sender sends N datagrams, the recipient shall receive the same N datagrams. Maybe out of order, maybe some will get lost, but each datagram is independent of all others.

Regarding the limitations, these are not so simple questions. There is plenty of information on these topics, just search.

The max size depends on factors like IPv4 or IPv6, fragmentation etc. and there is a best case and a worst case. Typically you can assume that one ethernet frame (for all headers + payload) is absolutely without problems.

The "unreliability" does not mean the quality of transfer is terrible. The network should work on "best effort" basis. It means there are no ACKs, timeouts and retransmits. You can live without it or you can add simple ACKs to your protocol.

Comment: I'm reading data from three sensors at the same time, the data received from every one have a high impact in my final result, that's the reason 'cause i can't use UDP. Looks very usefull, but could give me some serious problems if i don't get the full data at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example.

**Server code:** (read from client)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket, gethostname

s = socket()
host = gethostname()
port = 3399
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    print("Listening for connections...")
    connection, addr = s.accept()

    try:
        buffer = connection.recv(1024)

        response = ''

        while buffer:                
            response += buffer.decode('ASCII')
            buffer = connection.recv(1024)

        print(response)
        connection.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
        break
```

**Client code:** (send message)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket, gethostname

s = socket()
host = gethostname()
port = 3399

s.connect((host, port))

print("Sending text..")

s.sendall(b'-- VOID MESSAGE--')

print("Done sending..")
s.close()
```

Comment: The problem here is that i have no control over the server, i'm only have the power to modify the client, and all i need to do is receive all the data from the server, obviously, in the right structure.
At the start i'd tought that was easy, but is the data fragmentation what is giving me problems.

Ceirtainly, my client will never send data, only get and print, that's all. 

Thank you for help me :)